# Looping through the array from 6 to 14

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have a loop from 1 to 20

I want to go through the loop
only from 6 to 14

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To 19
        If i > 6 Or i >= 14 Then
           Writeline("My Name:")
        End If
    Next
```

This code works:

If i > 6 AndAlso i <= 14 Then Writeline "My Name:"

Above code wont work

Comment: Flip your sign. i <=14

Comment: Can you show us the code for the loop too? There is more than one way to create a loop.

Comment: If you are not doing anything else within the loop, you could use `For i As Integer = 6 To 14`. It doesn't have to start at zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If i > 6 Or i >= 14 Then Writeline "My Name:"
```

this is the same thing as

```
If i > 6 Then Writeline "My Name:"
```

maybe you should use

```
If i > 6 AndAlso i <= 14 Then Writeline "My Name:"
```

(The issues is with your > and your or)

Comment: `Or`, or `And`? Or even `AndAlso`.

Comment: yup, my bad, or would be all numbers! **Edited**

Comment: changed it just for you @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå ;)

Comment: Hmmm... did the OP mean to include the `6` when they said "from 6 to 14"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton i based the answer on the code provided, but yes, the answer might very well be i>=6

Comment: If i > 6 AndAlso i <= 14 Then Writeline "My Name:"  this one works thanks @starvator